# CruiseControl integration with ANT to build C# solution

Tags: c#, ant, cruisecontrol.net

I have installed CruiseControl 1.0.1 and Ant apache-ant-1.9.12 . I am trying to integrate them to build My C# project So I have done the below changes in 
ccnet.config

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <project name="VGProject">
    <webURL>http://localhost/ccnet</webURL>
    <schedule type="schedule" sleepSeconds="7200"/>
    <sourcecontrol type="nullSourceControl" />
    <exec>
<ant antscript="C:/Dev Softwares/Ant/apache-ant-1.9.12/ant.bat"
     antworkingdir="C:/Projects/vgproject/build/"
     buildfile="C:/Projects/vgproject/build/build.xml"
     uselogger="true"
     usedebug="false"/>
     </exec>
  </project>   
</cruisecontrol>
```

When i trigger a build it just says success without building . It says unused / node detected

My build XML is proper.Cruise control is not executing my build.xml

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Can anyone help standard ccnet config to integrate/execute build xml using ant.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing `ant` with `nant`. The question is tagged with both, but these are different products which are not interchangeable.

You have defined your build as `type="nant"`, but the executable you have given it is the `ant.bat` rather than the location of a `nant.exe`. This is the cause of the problem.

P.S. `cruisecontrol` and `cruisecontrol.net` are also different products: you should only tag with whichever one you are using.

Comment: My Projects requires ant , since the build type="ant" is not exist , i tried with Nant. I also tried with <schedule>
      <ant>
        <antscript>C:\Apache\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin\ant.bat</antscript>
        <antworkingdir>C:\Apache</antworkingdir>
        <buildfile>internalpush.xml</buildfile>
        <uselogger>true</uselogger>
        <usedebug>false</usedebug>
      </ant>
    </schedule> .However it does not help . It says unused schedule/antscript.